# while using Pyautogui in Tkinter for automtion, window gets resized and misplaced

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot, hotkeys, pyautogui

I have programmed a tkinter window for virtual assistant and I'm using pyautogui.
Following is the simplest code I am using to take ss after the func in called from button click in a tkinter window.
This program take the screenshot but resizes(smaller) and misplaces the window from corner of the desktop to the center.
Can any one help me with this why is it happning.

I have tried the  if _ *name*_ == '_ *main* _' for the tkinter file(main.py) and **init** method for pyautogyi file(screen_shot.py)
and i can't keep both of the in same file.

The same thing happens when i try to open webbrowser and use pyautogui to click on the browser window.
me tkinter

plz tell me what i am doing wrong or any solution to it.
thanks

```html
def takescreenshot():
    pyautogui.hotkey('win','printscreen')
    return "done"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyautogui changing my window size when I import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711836/pyautogui-changing-my-window-size-when-i-import-it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can stop tkinter to stop resizing by including following lines of code

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

If it dont works please let me know!

Comment: Yes i already have it in my code. I think its because tkinter must be using pyautogui too in its root directory. But I don’t know how to fix it